# Not able to save data in database in magento

Tags: magento, save

```
class NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer
{

        public function catalogProductSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
            echo $product;
            $model = Mage::getModel('testimonial/select')
                        ->setProductId($product)
                        ->setTestimonialId(10)
                        ->save();
        }
}
```

Here above echo $product work fine, means my call is coming in observer event.
Now while i m saving - nothing is added in database.
I have tried lots of thing, but nothing helped till.

Comment: please provide description of table and definition of models and model entities

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply @-OSdave. Problem is solved, i think it was due to cache. Now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs in `var/log/[system|exception}.log`.

Additionally wrap your database call in a try/catch.

```
try{
    $model = Mage::getModel('testimonial/select')
                ->setProductId($product)
                ->setTestimonialId(10)
                ->save();
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
}
```

Comment: 2013-10-02T10:54:18+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3645

getting error in System.log

Comment: it works after deleting cache & removed unwanted commented code...Thanks..!!@input